# JSON Swift 3 парсинг

Tags: json, swift, api, rest

Никак не могу понять, как спарсить JSON такого формата. Нужно получить photo, teaser, tags и. т. д

```
{
"response": {
    "count": 1722,
    "items": {
        "1871": {
            "id": "1871",
            "title": "На сахалинской мараловой ферме готовятся добывать панты",
            "slug": "1871-na-sahalinskoi-maralovoi-ferme-gotovjatsja-dobyvat-panty",
            "seo_keys": "рогов, фермы, мараловой, проходить, пантов, комплекс, мараловой фермы",
            "seo_desc": "На мараловой ферме готовятся добывать панты. В настоящий момент на ферме, которая находится в селе Новиково Корсаковского района, происходит отбивка самцов от самок. Для дальнейшей резки у самцов рогов. Процесс это сложный.",
            "seo_title": null,
            "tags": "фермы, рогов, комплекс, проходить, пантов, мараловой, мараловодов, маралов, комплекса, воздухом",
            "date_pub": "2017-06-21 09:48:06",
            "date_last_modified": "2017-06-21 09:48:06",
            "date_pub_end": null,
            "is_pub": "1",
            "hits_count": "1",
            "user_id": "1",
            "parent_id": null,
            "parent_type": null,
            "parent_title": null,
            "parent_url": null,
            "is_parent_hidden": null,
            "category_id": "16",
            "folder_id": null,
            "is_comments_on": "1",
            "comments": "0",
            "rating": "0",
            "is_deleted": null,
            "is_approved": "1",
            "approved_by": null,
            "date_approved": null,
            "is_private": "0",
            "teaser": "На мараловой ферме готовятся добывать панты. В настоящий момент на ферме, которая находится в селе Новиково Корсаковского района, происходит отбивка самцов от самок. Для дальнейшей резки у самцов рогов. Процесс это сложный. Проходит под контролем двух экспертов — мараловодов, которые приехали работать на Сахалин из республики Алтай. Основная задача — загнать всех маралов в вольер. Для этого сотрудники фермы образуют живой коридор, чтобы животные не смогли проскочить. В вольере будет проходить осмотр всего поголовья оленей. Далее самки будут выпущены, а самцы останутся до созревания рогов.<a class=\"read-more\" href=\"/news/1871-na-sahalinskoi-maralovoi-ferme-gotovjatsja-dobyvat-panty.html\">Подробнее</a>",
            "photo": null,
            "user_nickname": "Администратор",
            "folder_title": null
        },
        "1872": {
            "id": "1872",
            "title": "Ксения Лыгина из областного центра заняла первое место на конкурсе \"Островки живой природы в поселениях Сахалина\"",
            "slug": "1872-ksenija-lygina-iz-oblastnogo-centra-zanjala-pervoe-mesto-na-konkurse-ostrovki-zhivoi-prirody-v-",
            "seo_keys": "из южно сахалинска",
            "seo_desc": "Региональное управление Роспотребнадзора провело экологический конкурс фотографий \"Островки живой природы в поселениях Сахалина\". Всего в мероприятии участвовали 11 авторов, которые прислали 145 фотографий.",
            "seo_title": null,
            "tags": "фотографий, из южносахалинска, с фотографией, место, авторов, роспотребнадзора, конкурса, соответствовали, и были, на сайте",
            "date_pub": "2017-06-21 10:00:16",
            "date_last_modified": "2017-06-21 10:00:16",
            "date_pub_end": null,
            "is_pub": "1",
            "hits_count": "1",
            "user_id": "1",
            "parent_id": null,
            "parent_type": null,
            "parent_title": null,
            "parent_url": null,
            "is_parent_hidden": null,
            "category_id": "17",
            "folder_id": null,
            "is_comments_on": "1",
            "comments": "0",
            "rating": "0",
            "is_deleted": null,
            "is_approved": "1",
            "approved_by": null,
            "date_approved": null,
            "is_private": "0",
            "teaser": "Региональное управление Роспотребнадзора провело экологический конкурс фотографий \"Островки живой природы в поселениях Сахалина\". Всего в мероприятии участвовали 11 авторов, которые прислали 145 фотографий. Из них условиям конкурса соответствовали 72 фото 6 авторов, которые и были опубликованы на сайте управления. По итогам голосования членов жюри определились победители фотоконкурса. Так, первое место заняла Ксения Лыгина из Южно-Сахалинска с фотографиями \"Городской оазис\" и \"На пляжном острове\".<a class=\"read-more\" href=\"/news/1872-ksenija-lygina-iz-oblastnogo-centra-zanjala-pervoe-mesto-na-konkurse-ostrovki-zhivoi-prirody-v-.html\">Подробнее</a>",
            "photo": null,
            "user_nickname": "Администратор",
            "folder_title": null
        },
```

---

Вообщем вытащил данные через SwiftyJSON + Alomofire.
Теперь застопорился на этапе передачи этих данных в TableView.

На данном этапе код такой.

Не понимаю как передать значения, полученные в getJSON в другую функцию (в Таблицу) .
Для теста сделал функцию pGET которая просто печатает содержимое массива. Так вот за пределами функции getJSON этот массив пустой. Как передать значения из этой функции в другие функции? Помогите пожалуйста )

Изучаю Свифт 1 неделю, за корявость кода прошу строго не судить, раньше не был связан с программированием совсем.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

      var resFuncValue = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!




    var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      getJSON()
        pGet()
           }


func getJSON() {

    Alamofire.request("http://okha65.ru/api/method/content.get.news?api_key=534aeea9ee6176f0fd59d5527da4dd74a1").responseJSON
    {
    (responseData) -> Void in

        if((responseData.result.value) != nil)
        {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["response"].dictionary
                {
                    if let resItems = resData["items"]?.dictionary
                    {
                        for Count in resItems
                        {
                            if let resID = resItems[Count.key]?.dictionary
                            {
                               let resTitle = resID["teaser"]?.string

                                self.resFuncValue.append(resTitle!)


   //self.resValue = [resTitle]
   // print("Титл \(resTitle)")



                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }




}
    func pGet() {

        print([self.resFuncValue])
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

Comment: А что именно с форматом? Как и что Вы делаете? Что не получается?

Comment: Пришлось не комментарием, а ответом писать, ибо ограничение по символам

Comment: В каком виде это к вам приходит из сетевого слоя? Data, String, [String : Any]? Исходная точка не ясна, нет технических деталей.

Comment: А без технический деталей ответ прост: пришел json, берем и парсим его. Примеров кода на Swift километры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот должно помочь https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON есть примеры кода для стандартного парсинга и с помощью либы

Ну а ваш код выглядел бы примерно так

```
let myLson = try JSONSerialization.....
    let parsArray = myJson as? [String:Any]
    let secondArray = parsArray["response"]! as? [String:Any]
    let thirdArray = secondArray["items"]! as? Dictionary<String, Any>
    for item in thirdArray! {
        let newItem = item.value as? [String:Any]
        print(newItem!["photo"] ?? "nil")
        print(newItem!["teaser"] ?? "nil")
        print(newItem!["tags"] ?? "nil")
    }
```

---

Upd

var resFuncValue = "" // не массив а строка

---

```
func getJSON(completion:(_ success:Bool,_ array:[String]) -> Void) {

   Alamofire.request("http://okha65.ru/api/method/content.get.news?api_key=534aeea9ee6176f0fd59d5527da4dd74a1").responseJSON 
   {
   (responseData) -> Void in
       if((responseData.result.value) != nil){
            var result:[String] = []
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["response"].dictionary {
                if let resItems = resData["items"]?.dictionary {
                    for Count in resItems {
                        if let resID = resItems[Count.key]?.dictionary {
                           let resTitle = resID["teaser"]?.string

                            result.append(resTitle)

                        }
                    }

                    completion(true,result)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

и вызов метода

```
self.getJSON(){ (success,result) in 
    if success {
        print(result) //или можно делать любые другие действия с вашим масcивом
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. А как мне теперь значение result передать в ячейку таблицы? Немного не понял откуда метод вызываться будет. Из табличной функции я смогу его вызвать?

Comment: лучше до показа таблицы записать данные в переменную и передать их как параметр на ваш  UITableViewController

Comment: По Вашему варианту функции ничего не получилось. Не отдает значение она. В принципе и с моим вариантом то же самое. Внутри функции все отлично парсится. Почему не передает в другие функции не понимаю...

Comment: поправил ошибку в коде "result.append(resTitle)" и возможно  нужно поменять func getJSON(completion: (_ success:Bool,_ array:[String]) -> Void) на func getJSON(completion:@escaping (_ success:Bool,_ array:[String]) -> Void) И покажите как вы вызываете метод getJSON()